# How long does old client secret stay active with AD FS's ChangeClientSecret on Set-AdfsServerApplication?

Tags: adfs4.0

In AD FS 2016, when a new client secret is created using the PowerShell command `Set-AdfsServerApplication -ChangeClientSecret`, how long does the old secret stay active?

The documentation for the [Set-AdfsServerApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adfs/set-adfsserverapplication?view=win10-ps) command doesn't say how long it's active.

Note: The difference between `-ChangeClientSecret` and `-ResetClientSecret` is that the old secret stays active for a while when `-ChangeClientSecret` is used. Whereas the old secret is immediately invalidated when `-ResetClientSecret` is used.